# JHipster, AngularJS- After login, based on user authority how to take user to different pages

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

new to both AngularJS & JHipster and appreciate any help.

I currently have two user authorities, ROLE_ADMIN, and ROLE_USER. After logging in I would like to be able to direct the user to different pages (that they have access to). I believe I have been able to narrow down the issue to my sign in controller:

```
function login (event) {
event.preventDefault();
Auth.login({
    email: vm.email,
    password: vm.password,
    rememberMe: vm.rememberMe
}).then(function () {
    vm.authenticationError = false;
    $state.go('home', {}, {reload: true});

    $rootScope.$broadcast('authenticationSuccess');

    // previousState was set in the authExpiredInterceptor before being redirected to login modal.
    // since login is successful, go to stored previousState and clear previousState
    if (Auth.getPreviousState()) {
        var previousState = Auth.getPreviousState();
        Auth.resetPreviousState();
        $state.go(previousState.name, previousState.params);
    }
}).catch(function () {
    vm.authenticationError = true;
});}
```

If I change `$state.go('home', {}, {reload: true});` to `$state.go('trips', {}, {reload: true});` ('home' -> 'trips'), or change that to another page it works fine, so long as that user has the proper privileges, if not it goes to an error page.

Intuitively, I would like to add something like:

```
if (authority === 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
    $state.go('home', {}, {reload: true});
} else if (authority === 'ROLE_USER') {
    $state.go('trips', {}, {reload: true});
}
```

But I cannot find a way to access what authority I am in/using. I have also looked in auth.service.js and logged about everything I could think of to see if it is lurking in there somewhere.

If anyone has any suggestions or can point me in the right direction that would be very helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

stumbled across a solution with the help of a friend and wanted to share in case anyone else had the same issue... or, even better, a more elegant solution.

Looking into what `Principal` was doing in some of the other controllers found that `result` will return `true` or `false`

```
Principal.hasAuthority('ROLE_XYZ').then( function(result) {
    if(result) {
        $state.go('trips', {}, {reload: true});
    }
Principal.hasAuthority('ROLE_QWEQWE').then( function(result) {
    if(result) {
        $state.go('home', {}, {reload: true});
    }
```

As a result I just repeated and replaced `ROLE_XYZ` with the authority in question and that routes me to the page I am looking to get to.

Comment: Hello, to where should I add this code? and how do I access the Principle? Can you give a full view of the implementation? I'm trying to implement the same in my sign-in page after authentication success.

Comment: Hello! I added that to our "Sign In Controller", but you could use it anywhere by injecting it like `SignInController.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'Principal', ... ];`